# I have pass installed and so does my wife. Is there a convenient and secure way to share passwords with each other?

Tags: password, password-store

Both my wife and I use linux on different computers and have `gnu pass` installed. I want to share a few of my passwords with her. Is there a secure way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add her and your key GPG keys to the `.gpg-id` file in a specific sub-folder of your password store.

From the [man page](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/about/):

> `~/.password-store/.gpg-id`: Contains the default gpg key identification used for encryption and decryption. Multiple gpg keys may be specified in this file, one per line. If this file exists in any sub directories, passwords inside those sub directories are encrypted using those keys. This should be set using the init command.

So you might have a `shared` sub-folder with an override `.gpg-id` file like `~/.password-store/shared/.gpg-id`:

```
{your key}
{her key}
```

You can also use the `pass init` command with the `--path` option:

```
pass init --path=shared/ ${your-key-id} ${her-key-id}
```

From there, add passwords to the sub-folder as usual.

Then, sync the entire sub-folder to her computer (including the `.gpg-id` so she can add files too if necessary).

Comment: I'd be happy if I could just get one of the encrypted files on her computer and tell her to issue a couple of commands so the password is now available to her.

Comment: In other words, I'm not terribly interested in keeping them synched (although that would be cool if it were easy).

Comment: Without sharing the entire store, I'm not sure of an easy way to accomplish it.  Perhaps a different password store that's toggled through an environment variable?  But I'm only guessing.
I've updated the answer to include some more specific instructions, hopefully that answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not interested in periodic synchronisation, which I learned from your comments under the other answer, how about just grab the encrypted password files from your password store directory, and attach them to an email to her?  Then let her download the attachments to her password directory.

I guess this approach is simpler for one who doesn't care about periodic synchronisation.

Alternatively, if you are concerned about the trustworthiness of email providers, you may just give her a USB stick with the files in, then let her nuke it by `cp /dev/urandom /dev/that/usb`.

In order to not release your password store's password (might be different than your wife's), you may, as a previous step, re-encrypt the specific password files by another shared key, which you send to her by encrypting to her public key (she then decrypts the temporary shared key with her private key).  Or, directly encrypt the decrypted password to her public key.